# Web audio in Phaser 3 not playing on iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, phaser-framework

I've built a game using Phaser 3, and have implemented audio.

The game runs fine and sound plays beautifully on desktop browsers (Mac, Linux, and presumably Windows), as well as Android browsers.

However the game is effectively muted on iOS.

I've attempted the fix described [here](https://phaser.discourse.group/t/audio-works-on-web-but-not-ios/3677/2), by switching out web audio for HTML5 audio in the game config:

```js
audio: {
  disableWebAudio: true
},
```

When I do this, audio plays but the game lags badly and the sounds don't mesh very well so I don't really consider this a solution.

Comment: I really have same problem, if I disable web audio, sounds were playing after seconds delays, I really don't think that is the good way. Have you found any solution without disabling web audio?

Comment: @rener172846 What I had to end up doing was using a 3rd party library (Howler) to load and play sounds on iOS only. Not the best solution but it worked!